# Fetch all Restful Api data from Atera into my database

Tags: php, mongodb, curl, guzzle

I'm new to this Restful Api stuff, I'm currently using Restful Api from Atera into my MongoDB database.

This is the example from Atera Api

```html
{
  "items": [
    {
      "AlertID": xxxx,
      "Code": xxxx,
      "Source": "string",
      "Title": "string",
      "Severity": "Information",
      "Created": "2021-12-01T01:09:52.888Z",
      "SnoozedEndDate": "2021-12-01T01:09:52.888Z",
      "DeviceGuid": "string",
      "AdditionalInfo": "string",
      "Archived": true,
      "AlertCategoryID": "Hardware",
      "ArchivedDate": "2021-12-01T01:09:52.888Z",
      "TicketID": xxxx,
      "AlertMessage": "string",
      "DeviceName": "string",
      "CustomerID": xxxx,
      "CustomerName": "string",
      "FolderID": xxxx,
      "PollingCyclesCount": 0
    }
  ],
  "totalItemCount": 6783,
  "page": 1,
  "itemsInPage": 20,
  "totalPages": 290,
  "prevLink": "",
  "nextLink": "http://app.atera.com/api/v3/alerts?page=2&itemsInPage=20"
}
```

And this will be my code to fetch Api using Guzzle

```html
$client = new Client();
$uri = 'https://app.atera.com/api/v3/alerts';
$header = ['headers' => ['X-Api-Key' => 'xxxxxxx']];
$res = $client->get($uri, $header);
$data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

As you can see, I'm using Guzzle to fetch this, but somehow I can only fetch 20 items maximum, but what I can see is that it limits the number of items per page, which is 20 items per page, but I want to fetch all and I have more than 6000 alert items.

The Fetch that I have tried...
GET alerts?items=6000 
GET alerts?itemsInPage=6000 
GET alerts?itemsInPage[size]=6000 
GET alerts?limit=6000 
GET alerts?top=6000 
GET alerts?count=6000 
GET alerts?size=6000 
GET alerts?offset=6000 
GET alerts?limit=6000&offset=0 
GET alerts?limit=6000&offset=6000 
GET alerts?sysparm_limit=10000&sysparm_offset=10000 
and so much more...

Still, I'm only getting 20 maximum, is there any way to fetch all at once?

Answer (score 1):

From the api data you have shown above as example it is clear that the atera api you are using has a pagination system to send data.

You can see in above

```
"totalItemCount": 6783,
"page": 1,
"itemsInPage": 20,
"totalPages": 290,
"prevLink": "",
"nextLink": "http://app.atera.com/api/v3/alerts?page=2&itemsInPage=20"
```

Keep a note of total pages, then I guess you need to call the data via pagination nextLink only. You can show your data to the user or store it in the form of repeated calls synchronously as the nextLink comes in your response.

You can put up a while loop with a condition to exit with success if and only if the nextLink has finished(might be empty you need to check that), if there is a chance that response fails for some of them, you can throw exception and exit, store all of response data in an array.

---

Call your request like this for next pages `"nextLink": "http://app.atera.com/api/v3/alerts?page=2&itemsInPage=20"`

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$uri = 'http://app.atera.com/api/v3/alerts';
$headers = ['X-Api-Key' => 'xxxxxxx'];
$res = $client->get($uri, [
    'query' => ['page' => $page_number, 'itemsInPage' => 20],
    'headers' => $headers
]);
```

here you can set page number as per loop.